# Move Files with Same Beginning String to a Folder with That String Name

Tags: batch-file

So I have a set of files that look something like this:

```
[text A] (space) "(" [text 2].extension
```

example :

```
Joe (Nice Guy) (1993) (v.1).abc
Joe (Bad Man) (2001) (File B).xyz
```

I would like to do the following:

Scan the folder

Capture [text A]. In example above, captures: "Joe"

Create folder called [text A]. Here, "Joe"

Moves all files that has [text A] string to folder.

If file don't meet the string above just leave it without creating a folder and move.

I would like this to be extension agnostic as I have various file types (mp3, etc) for this scenario (set extension at the beginning of the batch file).

I always use :

```
@echo off
for %%a in (*.*) do (
md "%%~na" 2>nul
move "%%a" "%%~na"
)
```

but this freates 1 folder for 1 file. I can't edit it to work like i want.
Sorry i'm not good at that.

I use windows 10.

Comment: Instead of trying to do everything at once, start by trying to `Echo` all files which match the pattern, once you've achieved that, you can look at modifying the`Echo` to moving the files etc.

Comment: Maybe you can point me some tutorial on how to write the pattern for Echo command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply throw in an extra FOR /F loop to parse out the first token of each file name.

```
for %%F in (*) do for /f "delims=(" %%A in ("%%~nF") do (
  md "%%A" 2>nul
  move "%%F" "%%A"
)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man but it don't work exactly like i want. it take first word in file name instead of full string to "(" symbol. Can you help me to change that?

Comment: @SztucznaTwarz - I misunderstood the intent in your question. The default token delimiters are space and tab. Use the `"delims=..."` option to specify `(` as the token delimiter. I updated the answer

Comment: wow! man thanks a lot. respect. you save a lot of time for me! if you could add a line that leaves all files that do not have "(" in name without any changes it would be cherry on the top ;]

Comment: @SztucznaTwarz - I think I will leave that little detail to you. You only need to alter the first FOR loop to look for files that contain `(`.

Comment: @GerhardBarnard - Use of quotes instead of escaping `(` and `)` is much simpler. But either way, that can't work. It doesn't break at `(`, and also it will move files whose first token happens to match, but don't contain `(`.

Comment: @dbenham ok. it's fair enough. i was trying to figure something out but i fail. i'm greatfull for what i get from you anyway. respect.

Comment: @dbenham yeah, I posted without testing :) maybe better to do `for /f %%i in ('dir /b "*(*.txt"') do if not exist %%i md %%i && move "%i (*" %%i`